# Javascript: waiting for response from a MIDI device before continuing loop in asynchronous communication

Tags: javascript, async-await, web-midi

I am using MIDI protocol with web MIDI API to communicate to a MIDI decive.
I want to send MIDI messages to this device each time waiting for a response or a timeout to send next message. the response are received through.

I want the following:

```
//gotMIDImessage will be called when the message is received
midiIn.onmidimessage = gotMIDImessage;
function gotMIDImessage(messageData) {
  //Do something with the data
}
//send bunch of messages in a loop and wait for responce each time
function askDevice(){
  for (var i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<m;j++){
      midiOut.send([0xF0,0x52,0x00,0x61,0x09,0x00,i,j,0xF7]);
      //wait for gotMIDImessage or timeout to continue and do something about the response hre
    }
  }
}
```

This is my first attempt:

```
midiIn.onmidimessage = gotMIDImessage;

function gotMIDImessage(messageData) {
  received.innerHTML=received.innerHTML+"<br>"+messageData.data;
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(1);
    }, 100);
  });
}


async function askDevice() {
  var o = {'data': 'await'};
  for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<3;j++){
      var res=await gotMIDImessage(o);
      midiOut.send([0xF0,0x52,0x00,0x61,0x09,0x00,i,j,0xF7]);
    }
  }
}
```

It obviously doesn't work because `await gotMIDImessage();` calls the function `gotMIDImessage()` but this function fires automatically when a message is received.

How can I manage to do this?

EDIT: I tried also this version which doesnt seem to work

```
received=null;
midiMessage=null;
function gotMIDImessage(messageData) {
  received=true;
  midiMessage=messageData.data;
}

function sendWait(message){
  received=false;
  midiOut.send(message);
  function waitForIt(){
    if(!received){
      setTimeout(function(){waitForIt()},1000);
    }else{
      alert("received");
    }
  } 
  return midiMessage;
}
function askDevice() {
  var o = {'data': 'await'};
  for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<3;j++){
      res=sendWait([0xF0,0x52,0x00,0x61,0x09,0x00,i,j,0xF7]);
    }
  }
}
```

`res` is always null and I receive all the 15 messages after the loop is finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function awaitReply(msg, timeout = 5000) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const gotMidiMessage = msg => {
      midiIn.removeEventListener('midimessage', gotMidiMessage); // Removing the event listener again
      resolve(msg);
    };
    midiIn.addEventListener('midimessage', gotMidiMessage);
    midiOut.send(msg);
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Don't forget to remove the event listener
      midiIn.removeEventListener('midimessage', gotMidiMessage);
      /* Resolve the Promise anyway ... */
      resolve(null);
      /* ... OR reject it, but then you have to catch the error in the call */
      // reject('Error message');
    }, timeout);
  });
}

async function askDevice() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      let res = await awaitReply([0xF0, 0x52, 0x00, 0x61, 0x09, 0x00, i, j, 0xF7]);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a working example:

```js
function awaitReply(msg) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const gotMidiMessage = messageData => {
      window.removeEventListener('midimessage', gotMidiMessage); // Removing the event listener again
      resolve(messageData);
    };
    window.addEventListener('midimessage', gotMidiMessage);
    midiOut.send(msg);
  });
}

async function askDevice() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      let res = await awaitReply([0xF0, 0x52, 0x00, 0x61, 0x09, 0x00, i, j, 0xF7]);
      // Logging your iterator variable which you want to send
      console.log(res.detail[6], res.detail[7]);
    }
  }
}

const midiOut = {
  send(msg) {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      let evt = new CustomEvent('midimessage', { detail: msg });
      window.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }, 1000);
  }
};

askDevice();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I made a mistake in my code. I need to wait after sending not before. Doesn't seem to work as expected. I was thinking of using a flag but not sure how.

Comment: Yes, so using flags and settimeout doesn't seem to work as expected either. I really don't get it

Comment: yes, not working. Also how can we be sure that it doesn't resolve before asking it to wait for it to resolve? this is why i think it needs flags

Comment: Nope, not working. Maybe I dont understand the onmidimessage. Do I have to keep the declaration of the functions gotMIDImessage? I tried with or without and I don't get the logs in the console. Also I edited a question with another solution I thought about

Comment: I guess there is something wrong with my implementation because your example works on the code snippet, I will try to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, It works. So why dispatch it into a window event? and why the necessity of removing the evenListener in the promise?

Comment: I am not sure whether it is possible to use `.addEventListener()` directly on your midiIn Object. That's why I used a window event. If you don't remove the event listener, you are going to pile up a huge amount of listeners, since you add a new one every time you call the `awaitReply()` function.

Comment: Hmm but why do I keep adding and removing listeners? Why not just add one listener once outside awaitReply? Is there a way to add a timeout for no response? Edit: oh I see because the function gotmidimessage is in the function itself

Comment: I updated the answer with a timeout, default value is 5s. Regarding your other question: Well that's logically not possible... how would you resolve your promise from the first function if your handler is outside of that function? That would just bring you back to your initial problem. I can promise you, that this is the way to go. E.g. Node.js brings the possibility to add an event listener with `once()`, which derigisters the event listener right after it was triggered. We are kinda rebuilding it here.

Comment: Thanks, regarding the window event listener I think it is possible to do midiIn.addEventListener

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Why not removing the intermediate of gotMIDImessage? this works: function awaitReply(msg) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    midiIn.onmidimessage = msg => {
      resolve(msg);
    };
    midiOut.send(msg);
  });
}

Comment: That would work as well, if you're sure that you don't set the `midiin.onmidimessage` anywhere else in your code. The `addEventListener`-method is the safer way to go, since you don't have to worry about overwriting existing code.